# Get word after certain word in split array?

Tags: php

I have a path that is separated by forward slash.

```
$uri = getenv('REQUEST_URI');
$uri = explode('/', $uri);
$uri = array_filter($uri);
$uri = array_merge($uri, array());
```

The path would end up something like:

```
/user/john/account
```

This will grab the last word in the path, 'account'.

```
$uri = end($uri);
```

How can I get the first word found after 'user' into a variable?

In this case it would be 'john', but the name can change on every new URI.

'user' always stays the same word.

Comment: if you are using url rewriting then this would not be need to split. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$uri = "/user/john/account";
$uri_array = explode("/", $uri);
$key = array_search("user", $uri_array);
$desired_value = array_key_exists($key+1, $uri_array) ? $uri_array[$key+1] : "error";
echo $desired_value;
```

Here is what you need : Note : "user" is a fixed term in array_search .. you can change  it

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement your solution. I found one small problem, if the path is not complete "/user" without 'john', and $key+1, it will throw an error.

Comment: sorry its my my mistake .. its always good to check if array key exist

Comment: It's working now in a test. It will take a while to set up for the pages and I'll get back to you and accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before $uri = end($uri) add this:

```
$uriArray = explode('/',$uri);  //$uriArray[0] = 'user'  //$uriArray[1] = 'john'

$name = $uriArray[1];
```

With this you could also get the last element after a slash

EDIT:
You could also use preg_split('pattern',$string) like this:

```
$name = preg_split('user/',$uri);
```

$name would be "john/account". Then use explode again, to save it into an array, element 0 is the name

Comment: I had actually used this before, it selects a position, but I need after a specific word. It can still come in useful, thanks.

Comment: added alternative solution, maybe this can help you

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Use `M A SIDDIQUIs` answer. It is the better way to solve this problem

You can write a function for this that finds out whitch position of the uri-Array contains the word `user` and then returns the next position that should contain the name.

```
function getName($uri)
{
    $uri = explode('/', $uri);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($uri); $i++){
        if($uri[$i] == "user"){
            return $uri[$i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to print it out with:

```
echo getName("exmaple/user/username/etc");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$uri='/user/john/account';
$from1 ='/user/';
$to1 ='/';
//$uri = explode('/', $uri);

echo get_string_between($uri,$from1,$to1);

function get_string_between ($str,$from,$to) {
    $string = substr($str, strpos($str, $from) + strlen($from));
    if (strstr ($string,$to,TRUE) != FALSE) {
        $string = strstr ($string,$to,TRUE);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_match` might be more efficient in this case:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.1 (PHP 7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> preg_match('~/user/([^/]+)/?~', '/test/user/username/tuedelue', $matches);
=> 1
>>> $matches;
=> [ 
     "/user/username/",
     "username",
   ]
>>> $matches[1];
=> "username"
>>> |
```

So these lines

```
$user = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('~/user/([^/]+)/?~', getenv('REQUEST_URI'), $matches)) {
    $user = $matches[1];
}
```

would solve your problem.

Comment: This works well, though if I run it on any page that doesn't contain /user/ it will error. Is there a way around that?

Comment: How much faster/light on resource do you think this is than M A SIDDIQUI's solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42110367/6806643

Comment: You would have to try that out in your code ;-), I wouldn't know for sure. I'd bet under <=5.6 the regex performs better, and a tie for php >= 7.0 (or even the array winning); If I find the time a benchmark and comment again